# How to get all order collection in Customer account My Orders

Tags: php, ajax, magento, magento2

I want to add Order search functionality in customer account My Orders section. As if customer have many orders so they dont need to navigate instead of they can search by orders like this -

http://demo.dckap.com/m2/sales/order/history/

I tried to get customer session in `Magento_Sales/templates/order/history.phtml` page  but its not working.

Is there any way we can pass input search box value to order object ?

Or Load customer orders collection ?

Comment: your search is working what are you trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution to load logged In customer orders collection -

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
$connection = $resource->getConnection();
$customerSession = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
if ($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
    $customer_id = $customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();
    $order_collection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('customer_id', $customer_id)->addAttributeToFilter('increment_id', array('eq' => $orderId));
}
```

Then after that I have replace order collection with my order collection `$order_collection`  to get desired search order value from text box.

Comment: Just to add: never use the objectManager on your production/live website [Read the Magento2 docs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/object-manager.html)

Answer (score 0):

you need to override few files. you can try with below code, it should work.
for view access, override `canView()` function defined in `Magento\Sales\Controller\AbstractController\OrderViewAuthorization.php`

```
//overide getOrders() method in history.php block file as below
// to get customer id from customer session
if (!($customerId = $this->_customerSession->getCustomerId())) {
            return false;
        }

// to load orders for customer
 $this->orders = $this->_orderCollectionFactory->create()->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', array('eq' => $customerId));

//to add filter for search
if (!empty(<yoursearchterm>)) {
                $this->orders->addFieldToFilter(
                        'entity_id', ['like' => '%' . <yoursearchterm> . '%']
                );
            }
```

and finally add below line

```
return $this->orders;
```

Next you will need to override history.phtml and add your search boxes inside form. you can set action like below

```
 action="<?php echo $block->getUrl('sales/order/history'); ?>"
```

Hope this helps!!